# I want to transform multiple rows into a single row, single column and append comma (,) between the values with one Select Query

Tags: sql

I want to convert multiple rows into a [single row, single column] and append comma (,) in between the values. I want to use one Select query with no declare statement and no Utility.

[We can have any number of rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZnB3s.jpg)

Table:

```
ID 
1
2
3
4
5
```

My desired Output: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

Comment: So, which one DBMS are you using? SQL SERVER or Oracle? Which version?

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag with the database you are really using.

Comment: I am using SQL, But I don't want to use DECLARE Statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use `DECLARE`, you can use [`STUFF`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/ms188043(v=sql.110).aspx) i [`FOR XML PATH('')`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/ms178107(v=sql.110).aspx). For example:

```
DECLARE @tab TABLE (Id varchar(10))
INSERT INTO @tab VALUES ('1'),('2'),('3'),('4')

SELECT STUFF((SELECT ', ' + Id FROM @tab FOR XML PATH('')),1,2,'')
```

I assume, your `Id` column is type of `int` or `bigint` so you will have to cast it to `char` or `varchar`.

In SQL Server 2017 you can use [STRING_AGG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql).

```
DECLARE @tab TABLE (Id varchar(10))
INSERT INTO @tab VALUES ('1'),('2'),('3'),('4')

SELECT STRING_AGG (Id, ', ')
    FROM @tab;
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I was missing the STUFF keyword. It worked.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @Output VARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @Output = ISNULL(<value> + ',',<value>) FROM <table>

SELECT @Output
```

Comment: I'm assuming you are using SQL Server from the screenshot.

Comment: I don't want to use DECLARE statement.

Comment: Why don't you want to use DECLARE?

Comment: As per business needs, We don't want to declare an extra variable to achieve the result. We want to fetch it from the select query itself. Otherwise, I could have done it simply.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server you can use COALESCE

```
DECLARE @number VARCHAR(MAX);
SET @number = NULL;
SELECT
    @number = COALESCE(@number+',', '')+ID
FROM Table

Select @Number
```

Comment: I don't want to use DECLARE statement.

Comment: how come? you can use STUFF

Comment: SELECT STUFF((SELECT ', ' + cast(Id as varchar(max)) FROM MYTABLE FOR XML PATH('')),1,2,'')

Comment: MYTABLE: TABLE, ID: Column. I am using the above query to get the desired result.

Comment: As per business needs, We don't want to declare an extra variable to achieve the result. We want to fetch it from the select query itself. Otherwise, I could have done it simply.

Comment: Same I have mentioned in the description also that I don't want to use DECLARE statement.

Answer (score 0):

On Microsoft SQL Server:

```
DECLARE @CSVList VARCHAR(MAX) 
SELECT @CSVList = COALESCE(@CSVList + ', ', '') + CAST(ID AS NVARCHAR(100))
FROM YourTable

SELECT @CSVList
```

Comment: I don't want to use DECLARE statement.